# Batch File Protocol Parser

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

My custom defined protocol (phpfile) lets me open php-files in an editor through the browser. The only problem is, it gives the full url, that is different in each browser, i've seen:

- phpfile:/[file]
- phpfile:/[file]/
- phpfile://[file]/
- phpfile://[file]

All these need to be converted to just [file]. The problem is that I get a syntax error. What is the correct syntax?

```
set var=%1
if("%var:~0,9%"=="phpfile:/")
{
    set url = %var:~9% 
}
else
{
    set url = %var:~10%
}

if(%var:-1,1% == "/")
{
    url = %url:~0,-1%   
}
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\PhpED\7.0\phped.exe" url
```

=== Edit ===
I now have the following, but it is adding "" at the end of the url

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

set var=%1

if %var:~0,9%=="phpfile:/" (
    set url = %var:~9% 
) else (
    set url = %var:~10%
)

if "%var:~-1%"=="\" (
    set url = %url:~0,-1%"
)
if "%var:~-1%"=="/" (
    set url = %url:~0,-1%"
)

START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\PhpED\7.0\phped.exe" %url:"=%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were quite a few problems in your code, this should fix things:

```
set var="%1"
if %var:~0,9%=="phpfile:/" (
    set url="%var:~9%"
) else (
   set url="%var:~10%"
)

if "%var:-1,1%"=="/" (
    set url="%url:~0,-1%"
)
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\PhpED\7.0\phped.exe" url
```

You can check the syntax of batch file commands using `help <command>`. IF statements don't use curly braces, or require round brackets around the conditional statement.

Comment: Thank you, the only problem now is that the script is adding "" at the end of the url.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you wrote some horrible bastard between batch files and C but certainly no language that is in use anywhere.

Try the following:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=%~1"
if "!var:~0,9!=="phpfile:/" (
    set "url=!var:~9!"
) else (
    set "url=!var:~10!"
)

if "!var:-1,1!"=="/" (
    set "url=!url:~0,-1!"
)

START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\PhpED\7.0\phped.exe" "!url!"
```

Delayed expansion was used primarily to deal better with some characters that cause trouble in batch files. Generally though, I wonder how you would ever have expected your code to work.